# Cannot run application in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have simple gradle project created on my desktop in Intellij IDE. Everything seems to be alright there. I can run my application by right-clicking in it's context and choosing option `Run 'MyClass.main()'`. After finishing my work on this project I pushed it to my github and tried to import it to my laptop, so I can show it on university. There was no problem with importing but when I tried run it, I get following exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\io_evolutions\io_evolutions\build\classes\main;F:\io_evolutions\io_evolutions\build\resources\main;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.uncommons.maths\uncommons-maths\1.2.1\cc1d4ec8abf49e86080670d062575f43009f7d82\uncommons-maths-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.uncommons.watchmaker\watchmaker-swing\0.7.1\1f72e93816b5638f892dd0e1a98be7a5b3ffe605\watchmaker-swing-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jfree\jcommon\1.0.16\376f19a7c317509a57dfc684cdfd4081db7c082c\jcommon-1.0.16.jar;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jfree\jfreechart\1.0.13\b5fbdc552c4caec3dac4b4dcbc10d119a194946e\jfreechart-1.0.13.jar;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.collections\google-collections\1.0\9ffe71ac6dcab6bc03ea13f5c2e7b2804e69b357\google-collections-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Bartosz Sądel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.uncommons.watchmaker\watchmaker-framework\0.7.1\5e8b088427e972bdf4b5649a2d2dd39ed27197f2\watchmaker-framework-0.7.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain pl.agh.edu.evolution.experiment.EMASApplet
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/uncommons/watchmaker/swing/AbortControl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6220)
    at java.awt.Component.access$500(Component.java:186)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6174)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6172)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6171)
    at java.awt.Component.<init>(Component.java:6140)
    at java.awt.Container.<init>(Container.java:283)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:64)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:56)
    at java.applet.Applet.<init>(Applet.java:65)
    at javax.swing.JApplet.<init>(JApplet.java:131)
    at pl.agh.edu.evolution.experiment.AbstractExampleApplet.<init>(AbstractExampleApplet.java:26)
    at pl.agh.edu.evolution.experiment.EMASApplet.<init>(EMASApplet.java:35)
    at pl.agh.edu.evolution.experiment.EMASApplet.main(EMASApplet.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.uncommons.watchmaker.swing.AbortControl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get the same error on every other project run in Intellij on my laptop. It's the first time I'm trying to run application in Intellij after upgrading system do Windows 10. Is there some configurations which may cause this problem? I don't remember I had to set up anything to run it on desktop (Windows 8.1) but I may have forgotten.

Comment: It might not be an answer, but did you specify GRADLE HOME for IDEA?

Comment: Yes. Project is compiling fine using both Intellij and gradle. I'm getting error only when I try to run it.

Comment: How do you run it? If through IDEA, what are the Run configs? If as java -jar <?>.jar, how do you export the jar?

Comment: Through IDEA. Default config with path of current module where whole project got only one module. Config is the same on both devices. I checked it twice.